# AFNetworking block of code not being executed

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

I know that general questions are not allowed on this site - but I have a problem that doesn't really seem to relate to my code. This is one of those computer problems where my code was working one minute, and not working the next - and I didn't change anything. I'm going to post what I think is the relevant code - but I am not getting any error messages, either in my debug console in `XCode` or, on the server side, in the `apache2` error logs.

Possibly relevant code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], nil, nil, nil);

    NSString * uploadURL = @"http://192.168.1.4/upload.php";
    NSLog(@"uploadImageURL: %@", uploadURL);
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.5);

    NSString *queryStringss = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",uploadURL];
    queryStringss = [queryStringss stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    //manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;
    manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/plain"];

    NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *usernameEncoded = [[userdefaults objectForKey:@"pfuser"]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": usernameEncoded, @"count": [userdefaults valueForKey:@"count"]};

    [manager POST:queryStringss parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"file.jpeg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
              NSInteger count = [userdefaults integerForKey:@"count"];
              NSNumber *stored = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:count];
              count++;
              [userdefaults setInteger:count forKey:@"count"];


              GMSMarker *marker3 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
              marker3.position = mapView_.myLocation.coordinate;
              marker3.title = [userdefaults objectForKey:@"pfuser"];
              marker3.map = mapView_;

              PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:mapView_.myLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:mapView_.myLocation.coordinate.longitude];

              PFObject *pointstore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"MapPoints"];
              pointstore[@"title"] = [userdefaults objectForKey:@"pfuser"];
              pointstore[@"location"] = point;
              pointstore[@"count"] = stored;

              [pointstore saveEventually:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error");
                  }
                  else {
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                          mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
                      });
                  }
              }];
          }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
          }];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Above is the code that is supposed to execute. It seems to execute everything up until `[manager POST:queryStringss parameters:params...`

I don't see the `NSLog` success or failure messages, it just stalls out...the app doesn't crash though...the app continues to work fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated this morning (I'd be willing to work through it with someone, who knows what they are doing, in a chat or something like that). Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

PHP server side code:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$count = $_POST['count'];
$base64string = base64_encode(file_get_contents("images/".$username."/".$count."/".$username."file".$count.".jpeg"));
echo json_encode(array("image" => $base64string));

?>
```

**UPDATE**

This is where I am declaring `manager` now:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SignUpController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
@import GoogleMaps;

typedef void (^CompletionHandlerType)();

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
    BOOL firstLocationUpdate_;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    UIImageView *image;
    UIButton *respondButton;
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;
}

...
```

**UPDATE**

After some wonderful help from TheEye - we figured out, with postman (chrome extension), that for some reason the app just isn't finding the page...and I am getting a 404 response (from postman). I still haven't figured out why that is happening, anymore help would be greatly appreciated...but I might not respond right away, as I am tired.

Comment: You can't ping people who haven't answered / made a comment to your question. - And this doesn't seem to relate much to php?

Comment: Can you please try with writing 
"[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];"
at first.

Comment: Manager should be allocated outside your delegate method as an ivar (or possibly even independently as a singleton). In your case it is deallocated before the request is fully processed.

Comment: @Epodax only because of apache is why i put that - there is some php involved...ill post it

Comment: @DShah sure why not...but it seems like the third commenter might know what is up :)

Comment: @rokjarc ill try your suggestion too

Comment: sorry for late response all...i was playing with my cat :)

Comment: @rokjarc what is difference between ivar and singleton (both, where they appear in the code, and what the difference is from a programmatic standpoint).

Comment: @rokjarc i declared the manager variable in the implementation block...and still no luck. is that what you meant by `ivar`?

Comment: @DShah I am already using the code identical to your suggestion

Comment: @ewizard I will send you the code which I am using for same feature.

Comment: @rokjarc is right - the manager object is released before the response is received - you have to define it as property. Show the whole code where you implemented it.

Comment: @TheEye edited ill try it as a property now

Comment: Did you also SET the manager now on the declared instance variable or did you leave the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];` in your code as it was - that will override the instance variable

Comment: Properties are nicer anyway - but if it's used right it should not matter.

Comment: @TheEye what do you mean by "SET"?

Comment: @TheEye nm i understand

Comment: @TheEye does it matter if i make the property `nonatomic` or anything like that? i still dont really know what that stuff means.

Comment: It should be strong (meaning you want to keep the reference), and nonatomic is fine for most properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96967/discussion-between-ewizard-and-theeye).

Comment: @ewizard: with ivar i ment instance variable. The object (i guess it would be the view controller that also handles uiimagepicker) should instantiate manager outside the delegate method and holds a reference to it. A singleton would be a sucblass of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` with single instance running. This would make sense if you are making API calls from more than one place.

Comment: no problem :) glad to see you sorted it out

Answer (score 0):

Stupid firewall must have started blocking stuff randomly. I disabled the firewall and everything started working again.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

UIImage *fetchedImage = (UIImage*) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(fetchedImage,0.0);

 [self SetUserProfilePhotoData:imageData];

}


-(void)SetUserProfilePhotoData:(NSData*)imageData
{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 15000000000000;
manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
// [serializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manager.requestSerializer = serializer;





NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *usernameEncoded = [[userdefaults objectForKey:@"pfuser"]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": usernameEncoded, @"count": [userdefaults valueForKey:@"count"]};

NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@“http://192.168.1.4/upload.php” parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    //  [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"image"];


    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:"file.jpeg" mimeType:@"application/octet-stream"];


} error:nil];


AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
[manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                     [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Uploaded!"];
                                      });                                        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                              NSLog(@"Success %@", string);



                                     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"" forKey:@"UserProfilePic"];

                                 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                     [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Error in uploading!"];
                                     NSLog(@"Failure %@", error.description);
                                 }];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                    long long totalBytesWritten,
                                    long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {


   // NSLog(@"Wrote %lld/%lld", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

    float progress =  (float)totalBytesWritten/(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
     [SVProgressHUD showProgress:progress status:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Uploading %@%%",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", progress*100]] maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeClear];

}];

// 5. Begin!
[operation start];


}
```

Comment: I have added your parameters and .php URL

Comment: seems like you are being sarcastic with the time interval...gonna downvote this...unless u can explain time interval

Comment: i will downvote and flag unless you can explain that

Comment: timeoutInterval is required to Upload image of bigger size

Comment: you can comment that line. but I think you have wrote your issue is regarding not calling any block success/failure... so try given solution instead

Comment: float progress also seems unnecessary...i have asked a moderator to take a look at your answer